# What are the correct Android Legacy Apache Http Proguard rules and configuration?

Tags: android, apache, proguard

I have an Android AsyncTask which makes a HTTP call using Legacy Apache.
When I run this code in a non-minified build variant (ie not obfuscated or shrunk) the HTTP call is made successfully.
As soon as I use `minifyEnabled true` the code breaks with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class MyAsyncTask:

    java.lang.Object MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(java.lang.Object[]) failed to verify:
    java.lang.Object MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(java.lang.Object[]):
    [0x24] 'this' argument 'Precise Reference:
    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' not instance of 'Reference:
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient' (declaration of 'MyAsyncTask' appears in /data/app/org.xx-w1slvEAYxDsAOEktrVoz3A==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

The code in question is inside the doInBackground method and looks like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHead httpHead = new HttpHead("aUrl");

final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_VALUE);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_VALUE);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpHead);
```

I have the following proguard rules set:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-keep interface org.apache.** { *; }
-keep enum org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
```

I am using `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in my gradle.

I have added apache dependencies as well:

```
httpCore: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10,
httpMime: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6,
httpClient: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6
```

This setup worked with Android Gralde Plugin 3.1.2 but fails for 3.4.1.

Is my proguard configuration incorrect? Or do I have to update the code to use CloseableHttpClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these Apache dependencies and use `useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"` instead.

Adding both of them is nonsense, because it is not certain which one gets referenced & packaged.

If the imports of `MyAsyncTask` are broken then, it might have referenced the Apache libraries.

Comment: Wow that was actually spot on. Thank you very much Martin.
Having both useLibrary and the http component dependencies caused the issue. I removed the http component dependencies, fixed up a few imports and everything runs as expected.